# Scala compare two lists and build string

Tags: scala, loops

I have two lists as follows:

InputColumns:

```
List(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13)
```

InputData:

```
List(
  Map(col2 -> dummy string, col7 -> 2016-01-01, col11 -> 2011-01-01),
  Map(col2 -> dummy string, col7 -> 2018-01-01, col11 -> 2018-01-01),
  Map(col2 -> dummy string, col7 -> 2018-04-01, col11 -> 2018-04-01),
  Map(col2 -> dummy string, col7 -> 2016-01-01, col11 -> 2016-01-01)
)
```

What I am trying to do is generate a string after I iterate through them both. so if the colX names match then give it the value in the Map else give it the value NULL.

So in the example above I would loop through 4 times, creating 4 strings that would return:

```
(Null, dummy string, Null, Null, Null, Null,2016-01-01, Null) ..etc..
```

I thought of starting as follows. loop through my list of input columns and then loop through each key of my input data but I feel I'm a fair way off.

```
inputColumns.foreach(column => {
    inputData.foreach{ case (k,v) =>
        // I get a constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type error
    }
})
```

Comment: What's in the variables `col1`, ..., `col13`?

Comment: nothing, they are just the names of my table columns. I'm trying to build up a spark sql query that will help my insert dictate where the value should be placed in the string I want to build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `null` is generally discouraged in Scala, that is why I can suggest making this mapping to `List[Option[String]]`. This will allow to benefit securely from functional calls on the transformed data.

So, supposing you have these initial values:

```
private val columns =
  List("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5", "col6", "col7", "col8", "col9", "col10", "col11", "col12", "col13")

private val input = List(
  Map("col2" -> "dummy string", "col7" -> "2016-01-01", "col11" -> "2011-01-01"),
  Map("col2" -> "dummy string", "col7" -> "2018-01-01", "col11" -> "2018-01-01"),
  Map("col2" -> "dummy string", "col7" -> "2018-04-01", "col11" -> "2018-04-01"),
  Map("col2" -> "dummy string", "col7" -> "2016-01-01", "col11" -> "2016-01-01")
)
```

We can transform them in a `List` of `List[Option[String]]`, where each sub-list corresponds to the original `Map`:

```
val rows = input.map(originalMap =>
  columns.map(column => originalMap.get(column))
)
```

Each row looks like

```
List(None, Some(dummy string), None, None, None, None, Some(2016-01-01), None, None, None, Some(2011-01-01), None, None)
```

If you still want to use nulls:

```
val resultWithNulls = rows.map(row => row.map(_.getOrElse(null)))
```

gives rows like:

```
List(null, "dummy string", null, null, null, null, "2016-01-01", null, null, null, "2011-01-01", null, null)
```

And if you want to tranform optional to CSV-like string, it remains simple:

```
val resultAsCsvString = rows.map(row => row.map(_.getOrElse("")).mkString(","))
// List(
//  ",dummy string,,,,,2016-01-01,,,,2011-01-01,,",
//  ",dummy string,,,,,2018-01-01,,,,2018-01-01,,",  ...
// )
```

Answer (score 1):

Just map the header using each map in the input data. If you want to plug in some values that are not in the map, use `getOrElse`. This code here:

```
val col1 = "col1"
val col2 = "col2"
val col3 = "col3"
val col4 = "col4"
val col5 = "col5"
val col6 = "col6"
val col7 = "col7"
val col8 = "col8"
val col9 = "col9"
val col10 = "col10"
val col11 = "col11"
val col12 = "col12"
val col13 = "col13"

val header = List(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13)

val inputData = List(
  Map(col2 -> "dummy string", col7 -> "2016-01-01", col11 -> "2011-01-01"),
  Map(col2 -> "dummy string", col7 -> "2018-01-01", col11 -> "2018-01-01"),
  Map(col2 -> "dummy string", col7 -> "2018-04-01", col11 -> "2018-04-01"),
  Map(col2 -> "dummy string", col7 -> "2016-01-01", col11 -> "2016-01-01")
)

val rows = inputData.map { d =>
  header
    .map { h => d.getOrElse(h, "Null") }
    .mkString("(", ",", ")")
}

rows foreach println
```

generates the following output:

```
(Null,dummy string,Null,Null,Null,Null,2016-01-01,Null,Null,Null,2011-01-01,Null,Null)
(Null,dummy string,Null,Null,Null,Null,2018-01-01,Null,Null,Null,2018-01-01,Null,Null)
(Null,dummy string,Null,Null,Null,Null,2018-04-01,Null,Null,Null,2018-04-01,Null,Null)
(Null,dummy string,Null,Null,Null,Null,2016-01-01,Null,Null,Null,2016-01-01,Null,Null)
```

I'm not sure what you want to do with those strings, though. It's generally advised to avoid stringly-typed serialized-to-string-data at all costs.